# Queue with memory limited size

Tags: algorithm, haskell, data-structures, lazy-evaluation

I need a queue with next properties and supported operations:

- Push element in the beginning, automatically popping out from the end until size of queue become not greater than predefined limit.
- Take **N** elements from beginning lazily and not traversing whole queue.
- Limit by total size of all elements like 2Mb.

I know I can implement this by myself as a wrapper aroud `Data.Sequence`, or something else (according to [mentioned implementations](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/4lipsr/recommended_queue_package_xpost_from/)). Also found [this blog post](https://www.well-typed.com/blog/2016/01/efficient-queues/) from *Well Typed*. I just wonder is this already implemented somewhere?

And if there is no standard implementation with desired behaviour, it would be nice to hear recommendations which standard data structure to use to implement such queue.

There is [`lrucache`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lrucache-1.2.0.0/docs/Data-Cache-LRU.html) library which has almost anything I want except it limits it's size by number of elements in queue.

Comment: "while current size is greater than predefined limit" did you mean "while current size is __not__ greater than predefined limit"

Comment: @Alec thanks! My English is far from good. I rewrote that sentence to make it more clear.

Comment: "Limit by total size of all elements like 2Mb" what about sharing or laziness? How are you going to measure size?

Comment: @Alec In my current implementation I'm using `Text` data type, it seems not difficult for me to measure size (it will be even enough for me to use `length` as not so bad approximation of memory size). But I can imagine some API where you give `value -> Word64` function which tells you how to measure size. Or maybe there are even exist some tricks aka `sizeof` in _Haskell_. Regarding sharing or laziness: I agree, it's very difficult to calculate such values in general case.

Comment: My point is that sometimes it makes no sense. If I have a giant byte string and I add to your queue slices of it, what is the size of the queue? What about an unevaluated thunk? But yes, the question becomes solvable if you give a 'size' function. I'm not sure the output will be useful though.

Comment: You point to `lrucache` and say that it cannot limit the queue by size, but the [newLRU](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lrucache-1.2.0.0/docs/src/Data-Cache-LRU-Internal.html#newLRU) function which says "If a size limit is specified, the LRU is guaranteed to not grow above the specified number of entries." - does this not meet requirement 1? (Note: the 3rd requirement will absolutely be the hardest to fulfill - unevaluated thunks can be arbitrarily large, so you'll at least need to use `DeepSeq` as well as writing your `sizeof` function)

Comment: @user2407038 Yes, number of entries is not enough. Because entries can have arbitrary size in my case and I don't want overall size be too large. Regarding _unevaluated thunks_: yes, I agreed this is non-trivial. But I'm okay with `DeepSeq` solution, because forcing evaluation won't happen too often.